# How to extrude equally in all directions?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am new to blender and I'm struggling with one feature; a strip of metal going near the top of the camera body (Fujifilm s4400). My problem is that the metal strip will not extrude to a continuous length because of the curve around the camera body. To add to that when I smooth out the model I get a gap where the strip is and it curves at the end leading to a hole in the model.

Could someone guide me with what to do or edit my .blend file so that I can observe the way you do things.

[image]

Here is the blend file if you would like to have a look:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D1676DBCF8E08414!402&authkey=!ANRCxzBWbz75GiI&ithint=file%2cblend

kind regards,

Shane.

Comment: Sorry Zeffii, I did try to add more than one image but because I'm new here, my account doesn't have the permissions to share more than 2 links I've changed the title too now

Comment: Oh wow, I actually completely forgot that I have photoshop I'll get to it; and to answer your question I have the camera next to me so I am doing the modelling without blueprints

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The extrude tool can be pretty confusing when you want to do something simple like this, but if you use the '**Extrude Region (vertex normals)**' function in the Tools > Mesh Tools menu, you can do it. However, there is another tool that can handle your problem - '**Shrink/Fatten**'.

What I do is extrude (<kbd>e</kbd>), but without actually moving the extruded faces (to cancel the move hit <kbd>esc</kbd>), then use shrink/fatten (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) to move the faces along their normals.

[image: Using Shrink/Fatten to simulate face normal extrusion]

If you use Shrink/Fatten on its own, it won't actually create an extrusion, but can be used to move any existing face, edge or vertex along its vertex normals. I find it much less fiddly than invoking extrude along normals from the menu.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the late response I've had trouble with my ISP this has helped very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the **[inset tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset)** to create something like that. Select the faces you want to inset, press I and play with the depth values.

[image]

Comment: Set Thickness = 0 to mimic "Extrude"

Comment: Thank you for your response too; as I said to MrFlammy, sorry for the late reply I've had trouble with my ISP. I haven't tried this one yet because I've not long been able to get back to my computer. Just a quick question though, would this method be advisable for the job that I am trying to do? It looks like it may generate more geometry than the answer above? Looks interesting though so I shall give it a try. Once again, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Extrude is very counter-intuitive and kinda whimsical in Blender, especially when you want to extrude multiple connected faces. I found it really discouraging after using MAX and Maya.

Above answers give you most info you need, I'll add two things:

- F6 menu **after** extruding is your friend
- sometimes "use vertex normals" is the answer
- sometimes you have to make sure the correct pivot point and transform orientation combination is selected in the bottom bar of the window (I wish I could tell you what the "correct" settings are)
- sometimes it's important to apply object transform (rotation and scale) before extruding
- sometimes it's important to recalculate normals on all vertices before extruding

Comment: I am glad someone else thinks this, and I bet was hoping by now that the extrusion tool could do this simple thing. After all it has been 7 years.  Sadly, I think they are going to dig down and keep extrude and shrink/fatten as they are.  Probably because if they changed it 'the old people would get conf-u-u-u-u-sed'.