# scaling with an equal distance from each vertices

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a machete but when I'm trying to make it have a sharpness I extruded, loop cut the top of it so I could scale the front faces to give it a sharpness but how do I scale it so it moves all the vertices an equal distance away from eachother

thanks to anyone who replies :D

[image]

Comment: It's a bit unclear from the question what is your desired goal. Depending on the case, scaling is done with - Alt+S for scaling along normals of the faces, S with Pivot Point set to *Individual Faces* for scaling each group of selected faces up or down.

Comment: You can try the Inset tool. [related post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38907/19287)

Comment: I just used the bevel tool, thanks for ur answer :D