# How to extrude the selected faces of a cylinder symmetrically outwards?

Tags: faces, extrude

There is some way of extruding all the selected faces toward outside
 so that the extrusion is symmetrical in the object, using blender. Thanks for answer my question.

[image: Displays all selected faces that you want to extrude outward]

The I want is to do this in a symmetrical way, an extrusion outwards, 
I maked this selecting the faces indeviduously and extruding them outwards.

[image]

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38877/how-to-extrude-equally-in-all-directions

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will review the links, thanks for answering my question. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extrude all the selected faces out the same distance along their individual normals simultaneously, press Alt-E instead of E.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, I've already got it. with the information, that I was offered the Mr Zak. Thank you very much for you, for you reply too.