# 2 related(?) questions: How to scale or extrude multiple selections together?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I have seemingly related questions with gif examples provided below.

Context: In Edit Mode, when I select multiple faces or edges, if I try to scale or extrude them, the resulting behavior is unintuitive based on my expectations. I can't really figure out (a) why Blender is behaving in the manner it is, and (b) how to accomplish my goals quickly. To illustrate, I'll share two examples:

(1) Goal: In Edit Mode, my goal is to Scale two edge loops so that they both Scale evenly together outward.

Expected Behavior: When I select two edge loops and press "S", I want them to scale evenly together outward, just like when I scale one edge loop.

Actual Behavior: When I select two edge loops and press "S", the loops begin to slide along the mesh object.

[image: Example showing Scaling one Edge Loop vs two Edge Loops]

Questions: Why is it scaling in this manner? Any suggestions for a quick workflow to achieve my goal?

(2) Goal: In Edit Mode, my goal is to Extrude two separate faces so that they both Extrude evenly together outward -- in this case, the "top" face should extrude increasingly positive on Z axis, and the "bottom" face should increase increasingly negative on Z axis, evenly together.

Expected Behavior: In Edit Mode, when I select two faces and press "E", the two faces should extrude outwards evenly (in this case, in opposite axis directions), just like when I select only one face it extrudes.

Actual Behavior: In Edit Mode, when I select two faces and press "E", the faces begin to slide in unison along what looks to be the X axis.

[image: Example showing Extruding one face vs two faces]

Questions: Why is it extruding in this manner? Any suggestions for a quick workflow to achieve my goal?

Thanks so much in advance for your assistance!

Comment: In both cases you don't provide axis to move / scale the edges along hence it scales along all axes which is the result. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/slide-two-edge-loops-away-from-each-other and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38877/how-to-extrude-equally-in-all-directions. Please ask one question per post and upload images with built-in tool when possible

Comment: 1) Select both loops then `S` `Shift-Z` to not scale on the z-axis. 2) `E` `SZ` to scale on the z-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender, you can change the behavior of these operations like extrude and scale to suite your needs by setting the *Pivot Point*. The select menu is located in the bottom bar in 3D view.

[image]

In your case, you need to extrude or scale selected loops / faces individualy, so you need to select the *Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> for that.
For switching back to *Bounding Box Center*, use <kbd>,</kbd>

**The result - scale:**
[image]

**Extrude**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps a lot! Super appreciated :)

Comment: Please accept the answer so the question is marked as solved, thanks :)

Comment: I see, ok done!