# How to extrude vertex normals along an angle with an even offset?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I want to extrude all of the selected faces along their angle, at an even offset like so:

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38877/how-to-extrude-equally-in-all-directions and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/extrude-faces-along-local-normals

Comment: @MrZak They're related but do not answer how to do this at an angle.

Comment: The anser shown below works for the case shown in your question. *"doesn't work"* doesn't show *what* doesn't work. Doing the procedure on a rectangular plane (probably that you meant by rectangle) is not possible in general because there won't be any side faces to extrude. This all comes to the problem with your question - it is not clear what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple extrude and scale, however along custom [Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html), in this case *View*, in order to lock scaling on non-desired axes.

Select the face which is oriented at an angle (which looks like parallelogram). In the case of cuboid on your screenshot the one which is formed with the top loopcut on the side.

Align viewport with it so you see the face from the top. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> will do that.

Once viewport is aligned, select the ring of faces to extrude (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left click on faces near an edge).
Make *View* as transform orientation along which transform will be done - press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and choose *View*.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, cancel default extrusion and press <kbd>S</kbd> to execute Scale tool.
Now lock movement on axis you don't want to interfere. In case of described viewport position View X axis should be locked, so after enabling Scale tool press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (locks global X) and then again <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (locks View X). Move to the desired offset.

[image: gif-extrude-angled]

Comment: Way better than doing math!  But, uh, hardly intuitive (not your fault).  It would be nice to have an extrude tool with a bunch more toolbar options in terms of axes (and also shrink/fatten option) . . . but I'm not sure even that would cover this usage case.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it is dumb to me that it involves so many steps.  If someone knows a simpler way that would be good to know!

First you will have to calculate the ratio between the x and y dimensions of your object.  (**Edit:** see at the end for a more correct/precise way to find the ratio.)

[image]

In this case, my x/y ratio is 4.349/2=**2.174**

You will also have to decide how much you want to scale by.  Here I'm going to scale my shorter axis (here my Y axis) by 1.2.  Proportionally, that means I'm going to scale my X axis by 1+((1.2-1) / 2.174), or **1.092**

Now, in edit mode, I'm going to need to make a face.  Actually two faces.  What I suggest is that you select the faces as shown, then duplicate (Shift-D, then Escape).

[image]

Without deselecting anything, fill the empty regions with faces (type F).

Now select the first face, e.g. the top one.  Make sure your Transform Orientation is set to **Normal**.  **This means your X and Y axes may get flipped for purposes of the transformations (as happened in my case).  So you will use the X axis scaling for the Y axis, and the Y axis scaling for the X axis.**

[image]

Scale the X axis by typing S, X, X, 1.2, Enter  (don't forget to type X twice)

Scale the Y asix by typing S, Y, Y, 1.092, Enter (again, don't forget to type Y twice)

Now do the same scaling trick for your other face, the bottom one.

Finally, select both faces, and choose Mesh-->Edges-->Bridge Edge Loops to create your vertical faces.

Congratulations, you've extruded in what I truly hope is the fashion you were looking for.

[image]

**Edit:** on reflection, if you want to be precise I suspect you may need to determine the X/Y ratio not of the object, but of the face(s) you're going to scale.  Something something pythagorean theorem, I'll let you figure it out if it's important to you.  The above steps give something that looks roughly right.

**Edit 2:** or may I suggest the very handy **MeasureIt** addon that I just learned about, which tells me in this case that the Y axis of my face is actually 2.2 units.  That makes the true X/Y ratio 1.977, and the proper X axis scaling is 1.101.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use custom orientation**

**1.** Choose *Normal* orientation and select face with angle. Go to *N-panel* and find **Transform Orientation** rollout, press *Plus* to add custom orientation. Orientation called *Face* will be created.

[image]

**2.** Switch cursor to *3D cursor*, and change orientation to *Face*. Select face with angle and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (choose *Cursor to selected*). Select faces you want to extrude. Press <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd>. You should get something like this:

[image]

Because face was used as scaling center, lower part of extrusion went far way below. To put it in the right place you need to select inner border of edges and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (choose *Cursor to selected*).

[image]

**3.** Select outer border and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, but at this time choose *Selection to cursor*.
[image]